# Free/Libre download manager for android

Tags: android, open-source, download-manager

I am looking for a [free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) download manager aka downloader for Android 4.2 (jelly bean). I've searched in F-Droid but can't find any useful application.
Is there any Free/Libre download manager available for Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't find any useful application by searching [download manager](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=download+manager) or downloader on F-droid, But recently I've visited the category: [Internet](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdcategory=Internet) and started browsing all applications.

And finally found one [**GigaGet**](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdcategory=Internet&fdid=us.shandian.giga&fdpage=2):

> [image: screen-shot]

---

I've installed it and is working fine:

[image: screenshot]   [image: screen-shot]

---

I am also contacting to F-droid about this bug/feature-request that keyword `download-manager` should find this application as it says "Simple multi-thread download manager".

Answer (score 1):

You can try [uGet Download Manager](http://ugetdm.com/) which is open source and available for Linux, BSD, [Android](http://ugetdm.com/blog/3-stable/78-uget-for-android-112-now-available) and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try [G-Download Manager for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gagate.gdm)